# Wordpress: get_option to retrieve array

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the `update_option()` function to add the values of checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="BG[Choice_1]" value="Value_1" />1
<input type="checkbox" name="BG[Choice_2]" value="Value_2" />2
<input type="checkbox" name="BG[Choice_3]" value="Value_3" />3
```

When I look at the `wp_options` database table, the value of the field is

`a:3:{s:8:"Choice_1";s:7:"Value_1";s:8:"Choice_2";s:7:"Value_2";s:8:"Choice_3";s:7:"Value_3";}`

My questions are:

1) How do I simply `echo` the array values?  I assume I need to use `get_option()` but I have been unsuccessful

2) How do I default the checkbox to be CHECKED if the value is in the database?

Answer (score 3):

Ok... I figured this out...

```
    <?php
        $BG_options=get_option( 'BG' );
        $BG_Choice_1_checked = $BG_options['Choice_1'];
        $BG_Choice_2_checked = $BG_options['Choice_2'];
        $BG_Choice_3_checked = $BG_options['Choice_3'];
    ?>

        <input type="checkbox" name="BG[Choice_1]" value="Value_1" <?php checked( $BG_Choice_1_checked, "Value_1", "true" ); ?> />Choice 1<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="BG[Choice_2]" value="Value_2" <?php checked( $BG_Choice_2_checked, "Value_2", "true" ); ?> />Choice 2<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="BG[Choice_3]" value="Value_3" <?php checked( $BG_Choice_3_checked, "Value_3", "true" ); ?> />Choice 3<br />
```

Comment: you could also do: get_option( 'BG' )['Choice_1'];